# Server/Workstation for running 30 Virtual Machines simultaneously

Tags: hard-drive, memory, virtual-machine, cpu, virtualization

Consider the following scenario:

We have a student laboratory with 30 Ethernet enabled monitors. These each need to connect to Virtual Machines (VM), which run on a centralized server/workstation in order to be able to run different programs (for app development, simulations, etc.). Each VM needs to run Windows 10 and development apps (e.g.: Visual Studio or MATLAB) comfortably, so each VM needs at least 2 CPU cores and 2 GB of RAM.

What server/workstation would be the most appropriate for this task?

I have found several options which have enough CPU cores and RAM memory available, however my major concern is the speed of the hard drives. Currently I am using a 26 core, 24 GB RAM workstation for other purposes, and while it has enough cores and RAM memory, when running 2 or more VMs simultaneously it is painfully slow due to the HDD access times. That is why my major worry is the HDD setup. What would you recommend regarding this aspect?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered using SSDs (at least as cache on top of HDDs), or throwing more RAM at the VMs so that they wouldn't need to access the disk so often?

Answer (score 1):

Talking from experience: I am responsible for a setup, where 32 Windows VMs are run on a cluster (for redundancy, not for performance) and accessed via RDP.

If you dig into the IO workload you will see, that short random writes are what is killing your performance - and Windows is **very** fond of short random writes. This leads us into a situation, where the storage for writes should be very fast and low latency, while storage for reads (especially bulk reads) is less of an issue (and can additionally be mitigated by RAM as a cache).

We are using a 10 Disk (spinning rust) RAID6 as a backing storage but run all VMs with a snapshot, that goes to a RAID10 of SSDs and is consolidated into the backing file once per day.

This way we

- seperate reads and writes, being able to put them on different media
- have a very easy backup strategy: Just push the deltas to your backup location and consolidate there

If the backing volume comes to its limits on reads, use either `bcache` or LVM-Cache and another few SSDs to speed up access to the most-read files: This makes a big difference with application startup time.